# QGIS script processor not returning base file name

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to make a script that given a layer, let's call it "doc", discards the present fields (done) and returns a field with the base file name characters previous to lowerscores.
In the Model Designer, the Refactor fields does its job, given the SQL expression:

`LEFT(base_file_name(@doc), strpos( base_file_name(@doc), '_')-1)`

However, after exporting to a Python script, it does no longer work. The field is returned with only NULL values. It does work with plain text, I suspect the problem resides in the "base_file_name(@doc)" part, probably just the "@doc" variable. How can I reformulate it so the script works?
Edit: the code of the autogenerated script is this:

```
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : modelo
Group : 
With QGIS : 33203
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Modelo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('doc', 'doc', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Result', 'Result', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Rehacer campos
        alg_params = {
            'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'alias': '','comment': '','expression': "LEFT(base_file_name(@kmz), strpos( base_file_name(@kmz), '_')-1)",'length': 20,'name': '"FIELD_BASEFILENAME"','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'}],
            'INPUT': parameters['doc'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Result']
        }
        outputs['RehacerCampos'] = processing.run('native:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Result'] = outputs['RehacerCampos']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'modelo'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'modelo'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Modelo()
```

Answer (score 0):

*@doc* is a model variable taken from the description of the model input parameter, which is not set when it is used in the pyqgis script.

But you can get its value from the parameters dictionary. So, into the *processAlgorithm* method you can write:

```py
doc = parameters['doc']
```

And the expression expects its value between single quotes. For simplicity, you can assign the expression to a variable using a f-string:

```py
expr = f"left(base_file_name('{doc}'), strpos( base_file_name('{doc}'), '_')-1)"
```

Last, define the parameters for the refactor fields algorithm using the *expr* name as expression:

```py
alg_params = {
    'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'alias': '','comment': '','expression': expr,'length': 20,'name': '"FIELD_BASEFILENAME"','precision': 0,'sub_type': 0,'type': 10,'type_name': 'text'}],
    'INPUT': parameters['doc'],
    'OUTPUT': parameters['Result']
}
```